# How to Get the value of spinner in input box using jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Boot Strap spinner , in that how to get the value when Plus Button and minus pressed in spinner

by jquery

```
 var spinner = $("#spinner").spinner({
                min: 0,
                max: 5,
                create: function (event, ui) {
                    //add custom classes and icons

                    $(this)
                    .next().addClass('btn btn-success').html('<i class="ace-icon fa fa-plus"></i>')
                    .next().addClass('btn btn-danger').html('<i class="ace-icon fa fa-minus"></i>')

                    //larger buttons on touch devices
                    if ('touchstart' in document.documentElement)
                        $(this).closest('.ui-spinner').addClass('ui-spinner-touch');
                }, 
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this**

```
if($("#spinner").next().hasClass("btn") && $("#spinner").next().hasClass("btn-success")){
    alert("plus")
}
else{
    alert("minus")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through this working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z5tcf0kd/)

I have created New Fiddle using Bootstrap and JQuery.

> HTML Code

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <p>Min: -10</p>
        <p>Max: 40</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="input-group number-spinner">
            <span class="input-group-btn data-dwn">
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-info" data-dir="dwn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button>
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" value="1" min="-10" max="40">
            <span class="input-group-btn data-up">
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-info" data-dir="up"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> JQuery Function

```
$(function() {
var action;
$(".number-spinner button").mousedown(function () {
    btn = $(this);
    input = btn.closest('.number-spinner').find('input');
    btn.closest('.number-spinner').find('button').prop("disabled", false);

    if (btn.attr('data-dir') == 'up') {
        action = setInterval(function(){
            if ( input.attr('max') == undefined || parseInt(input.val()) < parseInt(input.attr('max')) ) {
                input.val(parseInt(input.val())+1);
            }else{
                btn.prop("disabled", true);
                clearInterval(action);
            }
        }, 50);
    } else {
        action = setInterval(function(){
            if ( input.attr('min') == undefined || parseInt(input.val()) > parseInt(input.attr('min')) ) {
                input.val(parseInt(input.val())-1);
            }else{
                btn.prop("disabled", true);
                clearInterval(action);
            }
        }, 50);
    }
}).mouseup(function(){
    clearInterval(action);
});
});
```

Simple and Responsive.